# Android OpenCV - Problems with detection of points using HoughCircles

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I have searched on google for a solution for detect points from an image using the `OpenCV` library for android (Java). I only need detect some points of the same color.

I tried using diverse codes those use `HoughCircles` method, but didn't work.

If any can give me an idea i will thank you so much.

**Update:** I'm using the method Imgproc.HoughCircles, how can i fix the parameters for detect points?

I found this code and playing with the parameters

```
Mat imgCirclesOut = sourceImage.clone();

Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceImage, sourceImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

Imgproc.GaussianBlur( sourceImage, sourceImage, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

Imgproc.HoughCircles( sourceImage, imgCirclesOut, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10000 );

float circle[] = new float[3];

Log.d ("InvisicodeAppDebug","imgCirclesOut.cols(): " + imgCirclesOut.cols());
for (int i = 0; i < imgCirclesOut.cols(); i++)
{
    imgCirclesOut.get(0, i, circle);
    org.opencv.core.Point center = new org.opencv.core.Point();
    center.x = circle[0];
    center.y = circle[1];
    Core.circle(sourceImage, center, (int) circle[2], new Scalar(255,0,0,255), 4);
}
```

But it takes too long. Again any help is welcome, thank you for your attention.

Comment: _"I tried using diverse code...but didn't work"_ -- that's pretty vague. What specifically did you try? In what way did it not work? What kind of help are you asking for?

Comment: I tried multiple examples, but they are focused on circle detection and no points. Any help is good; ideas, suggestions, code, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a broad, open-ended question and StackOverflow is not a good forum for it. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more information about why. You might try simply searching the web for point detection in image processing (or related phrases). Alternatively, rewrite the question so it fits the guidelines for SO.

Comment: I do and appears the OpenCV library. I tried some examples, even written in c++ and translated to Java.. but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a way to solve the problem.

First i improve the the gray image.

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur ( grayscaleWorkingImage,  grayscaleWorkingImage, new Size(1,1), 0);

Core.addWeighted( grayscaleWorkingImage, 1.5, grayscaleWorkingImage, -0.5, 0, grayscaleWorkingImage);
```

After I invert the image when morphology blackhat [Morphology Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

```
Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement ( Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size (10,10));

Imgproc.morphologyEx ( inversedGrayscaleWorkingImage, inversedGrayscaleWorkingImage, Imgproc.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel, new Point (1,1), 20);
```

Again improve the image

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur ( inversedGrayscaleWorkingImage,  inversedGrayscaleWorkingImage, new Size(1,1), 0);
```

At the end I can find the points with HoughCircles [HoughCircles Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

```
Imgproc.HoughCircles( inversedGrayscaleWorkingImage, controlPointsImg, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 299, 99, 3, 3, 7);
```

You only need change the function's parameters to your needs.